# Feign client: Avoid encoding in query parameters

Tags: java, spring, odata, urlencode, feign

I have to call a server that implements OData protocol. I'm using Spring and Feign client. I definend the interface as always and this is the method I wrote inside to call the server:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/resource")
ResponseBase<List<Resource>> getResourcer(@RequestParam Map<String, String> odata);
```

I have to insert `$filter`, `$skip` and `$top` dinamically based on context, so at runtime I create a Map that can contains one or more of these key words. In the scenario that I'm testing I have something like:

```
Map<String, String> odata = new HashMap<>();
odata.put("$filter=", "created_at".concat(" ge ").concat(fromTime));
ResponseBase<List<Resource>> response = repository.getResource(odata);
```

But this the url that is invoked:

```
/resource?%24filter%253D=created_at%20ge%201920202921
```

Is there a way to avoid encoding in query parameter? Or a easier way to call a rest api that implements OData using Spring?

**Edit 1:**

I used

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor myCustomInterceptor() {
    return new FeignDecoderUriInterceptor();
}
```

where `FeignDecoderUriInterceptor` has this logic:

```
public class FeignDecoderUriInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        System.out.print(template.request().url());
        template.uri(
                template.request()
                        .url()
                        .replace("%20", " ")
                        .replace("%24", "$")
        );
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work properly, even when is called correctly.

Comment: You might consider `RequestMethod.POST` (like posting a HTML form without long URL). URL parameter values need to be URL encoded (probably using some encoding like UTF-8 for free Unicode text), but will be decoded again at the server. I hope someone will give a better answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen it's for sure a solution, but I would like to keep the GET method to retrieve resources, as HTTP and RESTful suggest. Also I noticed that using Resttemplate of Spring I have no problem, I believe that some tricky configuration could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
odata.put("$filter", "created_at".concat(" ge ").concat(fromTime));
```